# Javascript foreach loop on list items

Tags: javascript

I have a basic HTML list like below...

```
<ul class="test_ul">
    <li class="item" id="item1">
        Item 1
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="item2">
        Item 2
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="item3">
        Item 3
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="item4">
        Item 4
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am using javascript to try and grab the id of each list item and then use a loop to check each one against a string.  I have this so far..

```
var myvariable
myvariable = "item2"
items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(item[i]);
}
```

This isn't working for me, is it because it is not really an array?

Comment: `console.log(items[i]);
`

Comment: getElementsByClassName => "Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.", you'll have to convert it to an array.

Comment: What do you mean by “not working”? So far you just log the indices of each element in `items`.

Comment: Yeah just noticed that, updating op now

Comment: `item` isn’t defined anywhere.

Comment: Why do you even need the IDs? Just use the elements from `document.getElementsByClassName("item")` directly.

Comment: You mispelled `items` in the log statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're logging the index `i`, instead, use `items[i].id` to get the id of the matched element. Something like this

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  console.log(items[i].id);
}
```

```html
<ul class="test_ul">
  <li class="item" id="item1">
    Item 1
  </li>
  <li class="item" id="item2">
    Item 2
  </li>
  <li class="item" id="item3">
    Item 3
  </li>
  <li class="item" id="item4">
    Item 4
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using ES6 (might need to transpile or add polyfills for older browsers):

```js
// Get the DOMCollection of node corresponding to the item class
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item")
// Transform the DOMCollection to an array and map item.id
  , ids = Array.from(items).map(item => item.id);
  ;    
console.log(ids);
```

```html
<ul class="test_ul">
    <li class="item" id="item1">
        Item 1
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="item2">
        Item 2
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="item3">
        Item 3
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="item4">
        Item 4
    </li>
</ul>
```

Using ES5 only:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item")
  , ids = []
  ; 
for(var i = 0, c = items.length; i<c; i++) {
    ids.push(items[i].id);
}
console.log(ids);
```

```html
    <ul class="test_ul">
        <li class="item" id="item1">
            Item 1
        </li>
        <li class="item" id="item2">
            Item 2
        </li>
        <li class="item" id="item3">
            Item 3
        </li>
        <li class="item" id="item4">
            Item 4
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Note that `from()` has limited browser support

Comment: @charlietfl polyfills/transpilers exist :)

Comment: Right but that was not mentioned. If OP didn't know and  ran this in IE would fail

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, I added the info. I'll also provide a more compatible code.

Answer (score 2):

You could borrow [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for an array like object and return just the `id` property of the objects.

```js
var result = [].map.call(document.getElementsByClassName("item"), function(o) {
        return o.id;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```html
<ul class="test_ul">
    <li class="item" id="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item" id="item2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item" id="item3">Item 3</li>
    <li class="item" id="item4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is, you want to loop through this list of items and find a match of the item based on a specified string.

What you've done so far with the classes is good. This will allow you to reference all the list items, but there isn't really a need for the IDs based on what I think it is that you're trying to do.

If I were you, I would utilize a querySelectorAll, which returns an iterable array of HTML nodes that we can do whatever we want with.

Here's my code.

```js
let listItemArray = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
console.log(listItemArray);
const SEARCH_STRING = 'Item 1'

for(let i=0; i<listItemArray.length; i++) {
  if(listItemArray[i].innerText === SEARCH_STRING) {
    console.log(`The item was found! ${listItemArray[i]}`); // This syntax is called a query string. Powerful stuff. Look them up.
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="test_ul">
    <li class="item" id="item1">
        Item 1
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="item2">
        Item 2
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="item3">
        Item 3
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="item4">
        Item 4
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add ID ="lstUsers" to ul element < you're registered with DOM now

```
for (var i = 0; i < lstUsers.children.length; i++) {
   alert( lstUsers.children[i].innerText);
}

#lstUsers  <--css with your id you shrink your HTML down this way...
```

Answer (score 2):

While all of the answers here are equally good, and this qs is old(2017)
I am posting this for knowledge sharing

We can use:

```
items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");//Get items
items.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);/*Use variable item for any need*/
});
```

If you need the index of item as well then use

```
items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");//Get items
items.forEach(function(item,index) {
  console.log(item, index);/*Use variable item & index for any need*/
});
```

The best of this is that it **doesn't need any loop** *or* **extra variable like `i`**. Also, it do not make use of a loop like for or while, but a function like `forEach()`, where *forEach* is a human-readable word

**Note:** `forEach()` cannot be used with `getElementsByClassName()` ,it supports only `querySelectorAll()`

### Working snippet:

```js
items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");//Get items
items.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);/*Use variable item for any need*/
});

console.log("The below log is with index");

items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");//Get items
items.forEach(function(item,n) {
  console.log(n,item);/*Use variable item for any need*/
});
```

```html
<ul class="test_ul">
    <li class="item" id="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item" id="item2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item" id="item3">Item 3</li>
    <li class="item" id="item4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```